# standard header for i2c and ISP?

Tags: pcb-design

are these the standard headers for i2c and ISP?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Which standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Atmel's datasheet, it is the recommended pinout:

[image: AVR ISP]

As for I2C, there is no recommended pinout in the NXP's [I2C specification](http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/UM10204.pdf).
I've seen a lot of different ones:

- SCL, SDA, GND, 5V
- SDA, SCL, GND, 5V
- VCC, SDA, GND, SCL

So feel free to use whichever you like more.

Answer (score 3):

No, sadly not. There are lots of pinouts that are used 'standard' by a specific manufacturer, but nothing that is realy widespread.

As an example, I like the Olimex UEXT:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any standard I2C connector pinouts as far as I know, although many individual board manufacturers probably have their own standard for compatibility between various boards they make. For the lower schematic what's marked as "SPI header" looks like the Atmel ISP6PIN layout, from the [AVR JTAGICE mkII](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc2562.pdf) documentation:

[image: ISP6PIN pinout]